# What is the use of cp -i command?

Tags: cp

Everywhere I read the following description.

> -i, --interactive  :::::::Before overwriting an existing file, prompt the user for
>   confirmation. If this option is not specified, cp will
>   silently overwrite files.

but I am not able to understand why the term overwriting is used here. If I am copying a directory to another directory, then what is overwriting here?

Somebody please explain me the use of **cp -i** with an example.

Comment: this sounds like a homework question.  regardless, just try it, `cp` a file to somewhere new, or where it already exists...

Answer (score 2):

The word overwriting is used while we are copying a file/folder to somewhere it already exist. 
Lets say we have two folders **folder1** and **folder2**, each one of them containing a file named **file.txt** 
So, if we try to copy the contents of **folder1** to **folder2** using **cp -i** command, it will ask us to confirm overwriting because the same file already exist there.